# hibernate search critteria by sample entity, id not on a property list

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate entity Car

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car extends AbstractEntityBean implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer carId;
    private Integer name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "carId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getCarId() {
        return this.carId;
    }

    public void setCarId(Integer carId) {
        this.carId = carId;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Then I try to search a car by example:
crit.add(example);

In "example" I set carName adn search works great, as expected.
But when I set carId in "example", carId is being ignored in search criteria and query returns all cars.
I did some debuggin and I see in hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final-sources.jar!\org\hibernate\tuple\entity\EntityMetamodel.java there is a property

```
private final String[] propertyNames;
```

I can see "name" on propertyNames list, but not cardId.
When I add annotation @Id to name instead of carId, carId shows up on propertyNames list and I can search by example where carId is set.

Question: How can I search by example using carId when @Id annotation is set at carId?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I remember from QBE with Hibernate criteria, this is the way it is designed. So short question, you can't query by the id using QBE. And it also doesn't make sense. When querying by id, you can only get one result.

As a side note: Hibernate 3.6 is quite old. Probably way out-of-date!